# Probability of Non-Consecutive Cards

Tags: probability, card-games

I've got a deck of 36 cards... 3 are labeled with #1, 3 with #2, and so on up to 3 with #12. I'm drawing 3 cards from the deck & wondering what the probability is that I will end up with NONE of the cards being within 2 of one another (including wrap-arounds--meaning a #12 is allowed to wrap-around to a #1). For example, {1,3,5} or {4,10,12} would qualify, but {10,12,1} would not.

I know that it's 38.9% WITH replacement as I actually drew the whole thing out on a spreadsheet with every possible outcome (and got 56/144), but I know that the number will increase slightly WITHOUT replacement, and I'm just not sure how to come up with the formula to figure it out.

I came up with this formula WITH replacement (using the inverting method)... 1 - {9/36 + (27/36 * 9/36) + (25/36 * 9/36)}, but I don't know how to adjust it for WITHOUT replacement. And I may have the wrong formula altogether. I'm new at this.

Is there anybody out there who wouldn't mind helping me out on this one? I've been at it for weeks with no luck!

Comment: Why not just count the good triples?  That doesn't sound so bad.

Comment: With replacement, you could get the same result by drawing three times from a deck of $12$ cards numbered $1$ to $12.$ I'm curious how you came up with $1 - (9/36 + (27/36)(9/36) + (25/36)(9/36))$; it gives the correct answer, but the factor $25/36$ does not seem to have an obvious motivation.

Comment: Lulu, I did count the good ones, and I came up with 56/144, but that's with replacement, and I want without. Dave, I got the 25 by subtracting out the ones that were already eliminated so as to not count them again (That's how I got the 27 too). I could show you my spreadsheet where I saw which ones to eliminate, but I think I'd have to E-mail it to you as I don't know how to show you that on here.

Answer (score 2):

### With replacement

With replacement, you can choose any card you like as the first card.
After that there are three cases:

1. If the second card is your number or your number plus or minus $1$ you have a bad set; this can happen $9$ ways out of $36$.
2. If the second card is your number plus or minus $2$ (which has $6$ of $36$ ways to happen) then there are $15$ out of $36$ cards that will make a bad set if they are drawn as the third card.
3. For any other second card ($21$ of the $36$ cards) there are $18$ out of $36$ possibilities for the third card that will make a bad set.

The three cases are mutually exclusive, so altogether the chance of a bad set is found by adding the three cases together,
$$ \frac{9}{36} + \left(\frac{6}{36}\right)\left(\frac{15}{36}\right)
    + \left(\frac{21}{36}\right)\left(\frac{18}{36}\right) = \frac{11}{18}, $$
and therefore the probability of a good set is
$1 - \frac{11}{18} = \frac{7}{18} \approx 0.38889.$

### Without replacement

Without replacement, there are only $8$ ways out of $35$ for the first case to occur;
the second case occurs for $6$ of $35$ second cards but only $13$ of $34$ third cards;
and the third case occurs for $21$ of $35$ second cards but only $16$ of $34$ third cards.
Now the sum of the three cases is
$$ \frac{8}{35} + \left(\frac{6}{35}\right)\left(\frac{13}{34}\right)
    + \left(\frac{21}{35}\right)\left(\frac{16}{34}\right) = \frac{49}{85}, $$
and the probability of a good set is
$1 - \frac{49}{85} = \frac{36}{85} \approx 0.423529.$

### Without replacement - alternative method

A second way to compute the probability without replacement uses the fact that a good set cannot contain two matching numbers.
That is, you must choose three different numbers from the set
$\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 12\}$ without choosing two numbers that would be adjacent on a clock face.

For the case where $12$ is one of the numbers chosen,
you can choose any two distinct numbers $x < y$ from the set
$\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 8\}$; then use $x + 1$ as your first number
(so $2\leq x\leq 9$ and $x$ is not too close to $12$),
and $y+2$ as your second number (so $x + 1 < y \leq 10$ and $y$ is not too close to either $x$ or $12$).
There are $\binom82$ choices of $x$ and $y$ in this case.

To cover all other cases you can choose any three distinct numbers $x < y < z$ from the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 9\}$; then use $x$ as your first number,
$y + 1$ as the second number, and $z + 2$ as the third number;
then $x + 1 < y < z - 1$, so the numbers are not too close in sequence,
and the $12,1$ case also is eliminated.
There are $\binom93$ choices of $x$, $y$, and $z$ in this case.

Note that for any set of three distinct numbers that does not include "adjacent" numbers (that is, for every good set), you can reverse the procedures in the previous two paragraphs in order to express the set either as $\{x,y+1,12\}$ or as $\{x,y+1,z+2\}.$
That is, the combinations in the preceding two paragraphs generate every good set of numbers once and only once.

So there are a total of
$\binom82 + \binom93 = 28 + 84 = 112 = 2^4 \times 7$
good sets of three numbers.

For each good set of three numbers, there are three choices of card for each number, $3^3 = 27$ choices altogether.

That means there are $112 \times 27 = 3024 = 2^4 \times 3^3 \times 7$ good sets of three cards.

But there are
$\binom{36}{3} = \frac{36\times 35\times 34}{3\times 2\times 1} = 7140$
ways to choose three cards without replacement from your $36$ cards.

As a result, the chance of drawing a good set of cards is

$$
\frac{3024}{7140}
= 2^4\times 3^3\times 7\times \frac{3\times 2\times 1}{36\times 35\times 34}
= \frac{36}{85}.
$$

### Without replacement - second alternative

Another way to count the number of "good" sets of three numbers chosen from
$\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 12\}$ is to choose any of those $12$ numbers first.
This leaves a set of $9$ numbers that are consecutive around a clock face;
choose $x < y$ from the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 8\}$,
then choose the $x$th and $y+1$st of the $9$ consecutive numbers
as the other two members of your set of three numbers;
there are $\binom82 = 28$ choices for that step.
This is guaranteed not to produce any two numbers that are adjacent around a clock face, but it produces each set three times (because any of the three numbers in the set can be the first one chosen).
So we have a total of
$$ \frac{12 \times 28}{3} = 112 $$
possible "good" sets of three numbers.
For the rest of the calculation, follow the part of "without replacement - alternative method" after the step where we find that there are $112$ good sets of numbers.

### With replacement - alternative method

With replacement, you are really just doing three repetitions of choosing a number uniformly from the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 12\}.$
Each number has a $\frac1{12}$ chance of being chosen each time,
independent of the other two choices.
So we can say the second card "ruins" the set in just $3$ ways out of the $12$ possible choices of the second card.
Another way to put this is, when working out the probabilities with replacement,
instead of writing $\frac{9}{36}$ we can write $\frac{3}{12}$,
instead of writing $\frac{15}{36}$ we can write $\frac{5}{12}$,
and so forth.

Comment: (+1) Very nice solution.

Comment: Excellent work Dave. You've tackled this better in a half hour than I did in weeks, and I don't think I'd ever get to this point had I kept at it forever. I'll have to study this long and hard to comprehend it all. It might take me a while, but it looks like you've given me all I need to get there. Thank you so much. And thanks for your help too Neat Math!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution for the case without replacement.

First we compute the probability of getting $3$ different cards:

$$P_1 = \frac{\binom{12}{3} \cdot 3^3}{\binom{36}{3}} = \frac{99}{119}$$

Next we compute the probability of getting a good triple from $12$ different cards. If all three are consecutive there are $12$ cases. If only two are consecutive there are $12 \cdot 8=96$ cases, therefore

$$P_2 = 1- \frac{12+96}{\binom{12}{3}}=\frac{28}{55}$$

Finally, the probability of getting a good triple from $36$ cards without replacement is
$$P_1 \cdot P_2 = \frac{99}{119} \cdot \frac{28}{55}=\frac{36}{85}$$

Comment: Also a nice solution. It turns out I was concurrently working on an alternative solution that also involved cards with three different numbers from the $12$ possible card values. I counted the number of "good" triples, which is $112$; you counted the number of "bad" triples, which is $12+96=108$; together these are all of the $\binom{12}{3}=220$ possible sets of three distinct numbers.

Comment: @DavidK Yeah I like that $12\cdot 28/3 =112$ thing.

Comment: I thought to myself, this is a neat, symmetrical problem; why isn't there a neat, symmetrical answer? So I looked until I found one.